# Get data from table which only have 2 status in a day

Tags: sql-server

I have to select data which only have 2 status in a day.

example:

```
|   Date   | Name | Status |
|:--------:|:----:|:------:|
| 20200222 |  BBB |      1 |
| 20200222 |  BBB |      2 |
| 20200223 |  AAA |      1 |
| 20200224 |  AAA |      2 |
| 20200225 |  AAA |      1 |
| 20200225 |  BBB |      1 |
| 20200225 |  AAA |      2 |
```

I need to get the `Name` which only have status 1 and 2 in one date.

Comment: Provide sample data as a text

Comment: Also provide (as text) the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a solution

```
SELECT Date, Name 
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY Date, Name
HAVING 
   MIN(Status) = 1
   AND MAX(Status) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```sql
    declare @test table (Date varchar(8), Name varchar(3), status int)

    insert @test values 
    ('20200222','BBB',1), 
    ('20200222','BBB',2), 
    ('20200223','AAA',1), 
    ('20200224','AAA',2), 
    ('20200225','AAA',1), 
    ('20200225','BBB',1),
    ('20200225','CCC',2),
    ('20200225','CCC',4),
    ('20200225','DDD',3),
    ('20200225','AAA',2)

    select distinct date, name, status
    from @test
    where status in (1,2)
```

**Edited:** 
This is NOT the solution. Sherkan's is, I did not understand well your first question.